# UV (ST) Texture coordinates in .dae file

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, collada, 3dsmax

I have started to work on OpenGL engine which will have to be able to import any model from 3D Studio MAX in OpenGL scene. Now I'm trying to import textures.

I export max model in .dae file.

In the beginning, when I was parsing geometry, I was wondering why there is "< float_array id="Box001-UV0-array" count="16" >" node when I dit not have any textures, but I left it as it is and just didn't use it.

Now when I'm trying to show some texture I read that the above node indicated texture coordinates. It sounded perfect to me, cos I have already been loaded texture and just had to put coordinates and I supposed everything will look just like in 3DS Max, but...it doesn't.

1. According to id of the node these coordinates are UV, but according to  node they are S, T. So what is the truth ?
2. I tried to change my material coordinates and export file again but for my great surprice where wasn't any change in .dae file. No matter that I changed coordinates in material, exported file has the same coordinates as before.

What I'm doing wrong ? Exporting file or....reading the .dae file ? What should I do in 3ds max to output right coordinates ?

EDIT:
So far I found one possible solution and it is not to make a material. Instead of that assign UVM unwrap to model. At least for now it works.